# Image decoding with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using OpenCV to decode an image from an array like so:

```
cv2.imdecode(img_array, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

However sometimes when I decode an image the tuple that I receive only has width and height without the channels. What could be causing this output?

Comment: I'm guessing this is because you have a grayscale image and not a color image

Comment: @Aaron that was my guess too. Is there any way ensure that imdecode returns a color image? The docs have been really sparse with this info.

Comment: If you give it a color image it should give you one back.

Comment: There's no way to force it to return a color image?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. You could convert a grayscale image to a RGB image if you wanted.

Comment: @Aaron that suggestion was enough to kick me in the right direction. Still new to CV2 but I'll probably use cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)